# Wakelock androida

Tags: android, java

Создаю свой плеер и хочу чтобы он не засыпал во время проигрывания. Запускал плеер пока так, без `wakelocka`, запустил проигрывание песен в наушнике и оставил на несколько часов. но музыка проигрывалась без малейшего намека на остановку. Сам телефон не трогал, внешних воздействий нет, оперативная память была предварительно очищена. В чем тут дело? Почему телефон не заснул? Перед тем как реализовывать `wakelock` в своей программе я хочу понять как он работает.

Comment: возможно, другая программа держит лок. А может просто система сама определила, что Ваше приложение выводит звук и держит лог для него. [вот программа](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) для просмотра wakelock.

Comment: Был ли телефон подключен по USB? Если был, возможно в настройках разработчика установлена галочка на "не выключать экран"?

Comment: да вроде оперативку почистил перед тем как плеер запускать. и телефон был от USB отключен, экран выключился сам конечно же.

Comment: а, тю, так экран выключился??    
Воспроизведение звука выполняется не зависимо от wakelock.    
То есть его не нужно устанавливать, что бы воспроизведение не прекращалось, это нормально...

Comment: вот как, спасибо :)
в таком случае второй вопрос: почему у других плееров (например winamp или интернет радио di.fm) требуется permission WAKELOCK при установке ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ, как не странно, нашелся в [стандартной документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#wakelocks). Всякие winamp и подобные видимо для улучшения звука, делают свою реализацию вывода звука. А в этом случае нужно иметь гарантию, что система не остановит приложение.